# Is there a Xively Development Server in Europe?

Tags: xively

I am updating my temperature readings with a 1-wire raspberry pi from South Africa.

Is there a xively server in Europe that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xively servers are automatically geo balanced. There is nothing you can do to force a specific server. Just use the API and the request will go to the best server at the time you send the request.